# Tkinter Button still responds to click after being disabled and updated

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want the button to start the command, then be disabled while executing and enabled again after the execution finished.

When I click the button, it appears to be disabled and the command is executed. But when I click the button while it is disabled, the command is executed a second time after it finished the first execution.

It seems like after the second click, the button is really disabled because I can click several times while it's disabled and it's only repeated once.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time


class Button:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame=tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button1=tk.Button(frame, text="Ready",bg="green", fg="white", command=self.click)
        self.button1.pack()

    def click(self):
        self.button1.config(bg="red", text="Busy", state="disabled")
        self.button1.update()
        doSth()
        self.button1.config(bg="green", fg="white", text="Ready", state="normal")
        self.button1.update()


def doSth():
    time.sleep(3)
    print("done")


root = tk.Tk()
b = Button(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Very strange. https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method suggests not using `update` inside a callback, but switching to `update_idletasks` only makes the problem worse - instead of permitting two clicks, it permits an unlimited number of clicks.

Comment: tkinter runs all in one thread. When you run long-running proces - like `sleep` - it stops `mainloop` and it can't correctly update widgets. Sometimes it looks like window freeze (hangs up). You should run long-running process in new thread

Comment: You should change your class name "Button" because tkinter has already a Button class. This will not fix your problem but it should be done. I know you imported tkinter as tk but still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click the button during the `sleep`, you queue a button click to be processed in the next update cycle. During the `sleep` tkinter doesn't update. After the `sleep`, you change the button back to normal state before the function returns and the click is processed. Since the button is active again, `click` is called again.

You can counter this by letting tkinter update *before* you activate the button again, this gets rid of any queued click events while the button still is deactivated.

```
def click(self):
    self.button1.config(bg="red", text="Busy", state="disabled")
    self.button1.update()
    doSth()
    self.button1.update()
    self.button1.config(bg="green", fg="white", text="Ready", state="normal")
```