# how to correctly disable tkinter button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have assigned a function to my `ttk` button and I'm trying to disable the button before `do_something_else()` runs:

```
def do_something():

    button.config(state='disabled')
    do_something_else()


button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Click Me", command=do_something, state="normal")
```

The above doesn't disable the button until `do_something_else()` is finished. How do I disable correctly? The behavior I want to achieve is to disable the button -> run `do_something_else()` - > re-enable the button.

EDIT

Accepted answer is correct, for more details refer to [Tkinter Button still responds to click after being disabled and updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535488/tkinter-button-still-responds-to-click-after-being-disabled-and-updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `button.update_idletasks()` to force tkinter to refresh the display.

Comment: this did not work for me :(